# Linux, is there a shortcut for executing last multi-lines command in terminal, instead of copy & paste

Tags: linux, terminal, shortcut

In a given scenario, I have a multi-line command which I want to execute multiple times, If I press `key up` I end up with the last line of the command, therefore, I need every time to copy the command and past it to the terminal.
Is there a shortcut to directly have the last command on the screen?

Comment: Try and ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I press key up I end up with the last line of the command

Your terminal may need `shopt -s checkwinsize`, so that it displays the line in full.

Another option, invoke `history` command, locate the command number in the output and then `!<command-number>`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca It always does, otherwise it would be worthless.

Comment: Managed to test (I'm on Windows, didn't want to fire up a VM and don't have WSL setup). Also, my terminal setup is not suspect, I think you believe I am OP?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca My mistake. Not sure why you try it on Windows, the question is tagged `linux`.

Comment: I was just saying I couldn't test before commenting without firing up a VM, since I'm on Windows. I fired up a VM, tested, and confirmed it works. That's the only reason I mentioned Windows.